# Fixed sidebar after full-page header

Tags: html, css

For my website, I implemented a fixed sidebar:

My problem is that if I set my sidebar `position` to `fixed`, then my sidebar is also visible in front of my full-page header. I would like my sidebar to start after my header, as if I had set its `position` to `absolute` with `top: 100vh`, except it would stay fixed when I scroll down.

How can you achieve this? Thank you very much in advance!

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

#header {
  height: 100vh;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  background-color:blue;
}


#main {
        margin-left: 20vw;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    
    sidebar {
        width: 20vw;
        height: 100vh;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #130E0A;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
      <title>Etude de controverse : Le théorème des 4 couleurs et les preuves informatiques</title>
            <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0'>
            <meta charset='utf-8'>
        </head>
        <body>
      <section id='header'></section>
    
            <section id='main'>
                <sidebar></sidebar>
                <div id='timeline' class='cd-container'></div>
            </section>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can you use jquery?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery you can go with something like that.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

     //>=, not <=
    if (scroll >= 1000) {
        //clearHeader, not clearheader - caps H
        $("sidebar").addClass("fixed");
    }
    else {
      $("sidebar").removeClass("fixed");
    }
}); //missing );
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

#header {
  width:100%;
  background-color:blue;
   height: 1000px;
}


#main {
        margin-left: 20vw;
        height:10000px;
    }
    
    sidebar {
        width: 20vw;
        height: 500px;
        display:block;
        background-color: #130E0A;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    sidebar.fixed {
      position:fixed;
      left:20vw;
      top:0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
      <title>Etude de controverse : Le théorème des 4 couleurs et les preuves informatiques</title>
            <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0'>
            <meta charset='utf-8'>
        </head>
        <body>
      <section id='header'></section>
    
            <section id='main'>
                <sidebar></sidebar>
                <div id='timeline' class='cd-container'></div>
            </section>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You need to change some styles if you want to add real content. And also a Tipp dont use vw vh to much it screw up in responsive. Only for fullscreen things. Like slider or stuff

Comment: Thank you. I can use jQuery, it's just that I have absolutely no idea of how this works.

Comment: you dont know how to use it? Or you dont know what it is. I can explain you both

Answer (score 0):

Look at this. Just changed some things in your html to html5 standards and edited the css. I hope that fixes what you wanted.

```css
#main {
    margin-left: 20vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
  
}

#sidebar {
    width: 20vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #130E0A;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0.9vw;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  I am the Header | Je suis le header.
</header>

<section id="main">
  <div id="sidebar">
    I am the sidebar | Je suis le sidebar.
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work... I appreciate the French though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a javascript solution that monitors how far you've scrolled and uses `fixed` when you scroll past the header

```js
var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
window.addEventListener('scroll',function() {
  var st = document.body.scrollTop,
      mt = document.getElementById('main').offsetTop;
  if (st > mt) {
    sidebar.classList.add('fixed');
  } else {
    sidebar.classList.remove('fixed');
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#main {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

#header {
  background: red;
}

sidebar {
  background-color: #130E0A;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

#timeline, sidebar {
  font-size: 5em;
}

#timeline {
  margin-left: 20vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Etude de controverse : Le théorème des 4 couleurs et les preuves informatiques</title>
  <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0'>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>

<body>
  <section id='header' style='height: 100vh; margin: 0;'></section>

  <section id='main'>
    <sidebar id='sidebar'><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p></sidebar>
    <div id='timeline' class='cd-container'><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p></div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but it doesn't work... The JavaScript runs fine, but when the condition is respected (st > mt) nothing happens, the sidebar does not become fixed... :'(

Comment: I found the problem: your code only works with the sidebar being a <sidebar> element, it does not work with a <div> (even with a 'sidebar' id)

Comment: @TomFévrier you have the same HTML and CSS in your code... that's where I got it from. I can't magically know you'll use different elements. All I can do is solve the problem in your post.